# Using Jquery to insert element/text before the first occurrence of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My xml looks something like this:

```
<entry>
<br>
<abc></abc>
<xyz></xyz>
<example></example>
<example></example>
<example></example>
</entry>
<entry>
<br>
<abc></abc>
<xyz></xyz>
</entry>
<entry>
<br>
<abc></abc>
<xyz></xyz>
<example></example>
<example></example>
</entry>
```

My goal is to add a new element along with text (e.g., `<example_header>Examples</example_header>`) before every set of `<example>` tags. As you can see, not all `<entry>` are going to have the same number of `<example>` tags and not all are going to even have one. I have tried the following JQuery hack:

```js
$("entry").each(function() { 
    $("<ex_header>").insertBefore('example:first'); 
});

$("<hr class='dict-divider'>").insertAfter("entry");
            $("<br>").insertAfter("hw");
            $("<br>").insertAfter("pr");
            $("<br>").insertAfter("ure");
            $("<br><br>").insertAfter("fl");
            $("<br>").insertAfter("dt");
            $("<br>").insertBefore("vi");
            $("<br>").insertAfter("example");
            $("<br>").insertAfter("syno");
            $("<br>").insertAfter("anto");
            $("<br>").insertAfter("suggestion");
```

```css
hw {
 color: #939393;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 350%;
 text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #fff;
}
fl, vt, spl, il {
 color: #939393;
 font-style: italic;
}
synn, antt {
 color: #939393;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 150%;
 text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #fff;
}
.dict_source {
 float: right;
 color: #939393;
 font-size: 100%;
 text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #fff;
}
sound { display: none; }
dx { display: none; }
sx, va, ahw, if, rv { font-weight: bold; color: #469046; }
ssl { font-style: italic; color: #883232; float: left; }
sn { font-weight: bold; float: left; }
svr { float: left; }
syno, anto { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<entry_list version="1.0">
<entry id="andar[1]">
<hw hindex="1">andar</hw>
<sound>andar01sp.wav</sound>
<dx>
<dxt>6</dxt>
</dx>
<fl>intransitive verb</fl>
<def>
<sn>1</sn>
<dt>
<sx>caminar</sx>
:to
<ref-link>walk</ref-link>
</dt>
<sn>2</sn>
<dt>
<sx>ir</sx>
:to
<ref-link>go</ref-link>
, to
<ref-link>travel</ref-link>
</dt>
<sn>3</sn>
<dt>
<sx>funcionar</sx>
:to
<ref-link>run</ref-link>
, to
<ref-link>function</ref-link>
<vi>el auto anda bien : the car runs well</vi>
</dt>
<sn>4</sn>
<dt>
:to
<ref-link>ride</ref-link>
<vi>andar a caballo : to ride on horseback</vi>
</dt>
<sn>5</sn>
<dt>
:to
<ref-link>be</ref-link>
<vi>anda sin dinero : he's broke</vi>
</dt>
</def>
<def>
<vt>vt</vt>
<dt>
:to
<ref-link>walk</ref-link>
, to
<ref-link>travel</ref-link>
</dt>
</def>
<example>
su andar era firme e iba a menudo con las manos en los bolsillos, sin demasiada prisa, como un hombrecito
</example>
<example>
el refrán dice: “dime con quién andas y te diré quién eres”
</example>
<example>
me pareció que andaba en tus cosas y le pregunté qué estaba haciendo
</example>
<example>
anduvo con él un tiempo, pero no funcionaban como pareja y decidieron dejarlo
</example>
<example>
a estas alturas y con lo que nos conocemos, no vamos a andarnos con remilgos
</example>
<example>
si vas a intervenir, ándate con cuidado, no vayas a meter la pata
</example>
<example>
se pueden escuchar los pasos de la gente que anda en el piso de arriba
</example>
<example>
yo diría que esta mujer ya anda en los cincuenta años
</example>
<example>
desde que ha intervenido el mediador, las negociaciones andan mejor
</example>
<example>
para una buena circulación de la sangre se recomienda andar
</example>
<example>¿Cómo anda hoy el tiempo? ¿Lloverá?</example>
<example>
las llaves deben andar por alguna parte, búscalas mejor
</example>
<example>desde que aprobó los exámenes anda bien contento</example>
<example>¡Ándale!, ahora sí que nos han descubierto</example>
<example>
anda, ven a sentarte aquí a mi lado y deja de quejarte
</example>
<example>
en el Camino de Santiago se anda una media de 30 km diarios
</example>
<example>
una botella de vino de las nuestras ya anda por los 5 pesos
</example>
<example>
el hijo mayor de Juan debe andar por los veinte años
</example>
<example>¡Ándale!, ya va siendo hora de que te levantes</example>
<example>
tiene unos andares muy vistosos y un pelo que parece seda
</example>
<example>¿Sabes dónde anda David? No lo encuentro</example>
<example>
el viajero que huye, tarde o temprano detiene su andar
</example>
<example>giré la llave de contacto y el coche no andaba</example>
<example>
el coche que te gusta debe andar por los 18 000 euros
</example>
<example>mis relaciones con el jefe andan peor cada día</example>
<example>tenemos mucho trabajo, así que ¡andando!</example>
<example>¡Ándale!, ese vestido te queda perfecto</example>
<example>para que ande el reloj, es necesario darle cuerda</example>
<example>anda, márchate o perderás el tren</example>
<example>anduvo durante el verano por el sur de Italia</example>
<example>no andes con esa navaja que te puedes cortar</example>
<example>anda con la moto por la urbanización</example>
<example>las cosas no andan muy bien este año</example>
<example>¡Ándale! chulita, dame un beso</example>
<example>¿Por dónde anda este pueblo?</example>
<example>anduvo un tiempo metido en política</example>
<example>anda por ahí divirtiéndose</example>
<example>anda con problemas en la vesícula</example>
<example>anda a que te devuelvan bien el cambio</example>
<example>andaba en trámites de divorcio</example>
<example>anda para adentro, que te vas a helar</example>
<example>¡Anda! Se cree que somos tontos</example>
<example>andaba marzo cuando lo conocí</example>
<example>andaba por la calle sin rumbo fijo</example>
<example>¡Anda, si ya son las cuatro!</example>
<example>¡Andando! Que llegamos tarde</example>
<example>andar en bicicleta</example>
<example>andar a garrotazos</example>
<example>andaba fastidiado</example>
<example>andar a caballo</example>
<example>andar resfriado</example>
<example>las horas andan</example>
<example>andar deprisa</example>
<example>andar a gatas</example>
<synant>
<synonym>
<syno>ir</syno>
<syno>venir</syno>
<br/>
<syno>funcionar</syno>
<syno>marchar</syno>
<br/>
<syno>recorrer</syno>
<syno>caminar</syno>
<syno>pasear</syno>
<syno>patear</syno>
<syno>desviarse</syno>
<br/>
</synonym>
<antonym>
<anto>pararse</anto>
<anto>detenerse</anto>
<anto>desandar</anto>
<br/>
</antonym>
</synant>
<synant>
<synonym>
<syno>ir</syno>
<syno>venir</syno>
<br/>
<syno>funcionar</syno>
<syno>marchar</syno>
<br/>
<syno>recorrer</syno>
<syno>caminar</syno>
<syno>pasear</syno>
<syno>patear</syno>
<syno>desviarse</syno>
<br/>
</synonym>
<antonym>
<anto>pararse</anto>
<anto>detenerse</anto>
<anto>desandar</anto>
<br/>
</antonym>
</synant>
</entry>
<entry id="andar[2]">
<hw hindex="2">andar</hw>
<sound>andar02sp.wav</sound>
<fl>masculine noun</fl>
<def>
<dt>
:
<ref-link>walk</ref-link>
,
<ref-link>gait</ref-link>
</dt>
</def>
<example>
su andar era firme e iba a menudo con las manos en los bolsillos, sin demasiada prisa, como un hombrecito
</example>
<example>
el refrán dice: “dime con quién andas y te diré quién eres”
</example>
<example>
me pareció que andaba en tus cosas y le pregunté qué estaba haciendo
</example>
<example>
anduvo con él un tiempo, pero no funcionaban como pareja y decidieron dejarlo
</example>
<example>
a estas alturas y con lo que nos conocemos, no vamos a andarnos con remilgos
</example>
<example>
si vas a intervenir, ándate con cuidado, no vayas a meter la pata
</example>
<example>
se pueden escuchar los pasos de la gente que anda en el piso de arriba
</example>
<example>
yo diría que esta mujer ya anda en los cincuenta años
</example>
<example>
desde que ha intervenido el mediador, las negociaciones andan mejor
</example>
<example>
para una buena circulación de la sangre se recomienda andar
</example>
<example>¿Cómo anda hoy el tiempo? ¿Lloverá?</example>
<example>
las llaves deben andar por alguna parte, búscalas mejor
</example>
<example>desde que aprobó los exámenes anda bien contento</example>
<example>¡Ándale!, ahora sí que nos han descubierto</example>
<example>
anda, ven a sentarte aquí a mi lado y deja de quejarte
</example>
<example>
en el Camino de Santiago se anda una media de 30 km diarios
</example>
<example>
una botella de vino de las nuestras ya anda por los 5 pesos
</example>
<example>
el hijo mayor de Juan debe andar por los veinte años
</example>
<example>¡Ándale!, ya va siendo hora de que te levantes</example>
<example>
tiene unos andares muy vistosos y un pelo que parece seda
</example>
<example>¿Sabes dónde anda David? No lo encuentro</example>
<example>
el viajero que huye, tarde o temprano detiene su andar
</example>
<example>giré la llave de contacto y el coche no andaba</example>
<example>
el coche que te gusta debe andar por los 18 000 euros
</example>
<example>mis relaciones con el jefe andan peor cada día</example>
<example>tenemos mucho trabajo, así que ¡andando!</example>
<example>¡Ándale!, ese vestido te queda perfecto</example>
<example>para que ande el reloj, es necesario darle cuerda</example>
<example>anda, márchate o perderás el tren</example>
<example>anduvo durante el verano por el sur de Italia</example>
<example>no andes con esa navaja que te puedes cortar</example>
<example>anda con la moto por la urbanización</example>
<example>las cosas no andan muy bien este año</example>
<example>¡Ándale! chulita, dame un beso</example>
<example>¿Por dónde anda este pueblo?</example>
<example>anduvo un tiempo metido en política</example>
<example>anda por ahí divirtiéndose</example>
<example>anda con problemas en la vesícula</example>
<example>anda a que te devuelvan bien el cambio</example>
<example>andaba en trámites de divorcio</example>
<example>anda para adentro, que te vas a helar</example>
<example>¡Anda! Se cree que somos tontos</example>
<example>andaba marzo cuando lo conocí</example>
<example>andaba por la calle sin rumbo fijo</example>
<example>¡Anda, si ya son las cuatro!</example>
<example>¡Andando! Que llegamos tarde</example>
<example>andar en bicicleta</example>
<example>andar a garrotazos</example>
<example>andaba fastidiado</example>
<example>andar a caballo</example>
<example>andar resfriado</example>
<example>las horas andan</example>
<example>andar deprisa</example>
<example>andar a gatas</example>
</entry>
<entry id="gatas">
<hw>gatas</hw>
<fl>adverb</fl>
<def>
<svr>
<va>andar a gatas</va>
</svr>
<dt>:to crawl, to go on all fours</dt>
</def>
<example>
se puso a andar a gatas, husmeando y palpando entre la arenisca
</example>
</entry>
<entry id="ojo">
<hw>ojo</hw>
<sound>ojo0001sp.wav</sound>
<fl>masculine noun</fl>
<def>
<sn>1</sn>
<dt>
:
<ref-link>eye</ref-link>
</dt>
<sn>2</sn>
<dt>
:
<ref-link>judgment</ref-link>
,
<ref-link>sharpness</ref-link>
<vi>
tener buen ojo para : to be a good judge of, to have a good eye for
</vi>
</dt>
<sn>3</sn>
<dt>
:
<ref-link>hole</ref-link>
(in cheese),
<ref-link>eye</ref-link>
(in a needle),
<ref-link>center</ref-link>
(of a storm)
</dt>
<sn>4</sn>
<dt>
:
<ref-link>span</ref-link>
(of a bridge)
</dt>
<sn>5</sn>
<svr>
<va>a ojos vistas</va>
</svr>
<dt>
:
<ref-link>openly</ref-link>
,
<ref-link>publicly</ref-link>
</dt>
<sn>6</sn>
<svr>
<va>andar con ojo</va>
</svr>
<dt>:to be careful</dt>
<sn>7</sn>
<svr>
<va>ojo de agua</va>
</svr>
<ssl>Mex</ssl>
<dt>
:
<ref-link>spring</ref-link>
,
<ref-link>source</ref-link>
</dt>
<sn>8</sn>
<svr>
<va>¡ojo!</va>
</svr>
<dt>:look out!, pay attention!</dt>
</def>
<example>
los huracanes son enormes cumulonimbos y nimboestratos de hasta 15 km de altura, dispuestos en espiral y formando una muralla alrededor de un anillo central u ojo del huracán, que carece de vientos, nubes y precipitaciones
</example>
<example>
antes de que se caiga el puente, tratarán de repartir el peso colocando pilares en los ojos
</example>
<example>
hay que preparar pronto estas patatas porque les están saliendo muchos ojos
</example>
<example>
con que le des un ojo de jabón a los pantalones, será suficiente
</example>
<example>
abría y cerraba los ojos como si tuviera un tic nervioso
</example>
<example>mantuvo los ojos fijos en mí hasta hacerme sudar</example>
<example>introducimos la llave por el ojo de la cerradura</example>
<example>ándese con ojo, no vaya a meter la pata</example>
<example>el hilo se mete por el ojo de la aguja</example>
<example>al echar aceite en agua se forman ojos</example>
<example>voy con mucho ojo para no equivocarme</example>
<example>se me ha metido algo en el ojo</example>
<example>ser tuerto del ojo izquierdo</example>
<example>sus ojos delataban tristeza</example>
<example>los ojos del queso gruyer</example>
<example>el ojo del azadón</example>
<example>tener los ojos azules</example>
<example>el ojo del martillo</example>
<example>los ojos del pan</example>
<example>el ojo derecho</example>
</entry>
<entry id="rueda[2]">
<hw hindex="2">rueda</hw>
<sound>rueda02sp.wav</sound>
<fl>feminine noun</fl>
<def>
<sn>1</sn>
<dt>
:
<ref-link>wheel</ref-link>
</dt>
<sn>2</sn>
<dt>
<sx>rodaja</sx>
:round slice
</dt>
<sn>3</sn>
<dt>
:
<ref-link>circle</ref-link>
,
<ref-link>ring</ref-link>
</dt>
<sn>4</sn>
<svr>
<va>rueda de andar</va>
</svr>
<dt>
:
<ref-link>treadmill</ref-link>
</dt>
<sn>5</sn>
<svr>
<va>rueda de prensa</va>
</svr>
<dt>:press conference</dt>
<sn>6</sn>
<svr>
<va>ir sobre ruedas</va>
</svr>
<dt>:to go smoothly</dt>
</def>
<example>
el hombre fue capaz de producir cuerpos y vasijas circulares más perfectos cuando se inventó la rueda del alfarero
</example>
<example>
durante este tiempo tu madre, rueda catalina de la máquina palaciega, permaneció en la corte junto a la reina
</example>
<example>
en aquellos días me habían hartado un poco entre todos con sus continuas ruedas de protestas
</example>
<example>
dijo que no quería que ese periodista estuviese en la rueda de prensa y lo sacó de la sala
</example>
<example>
el gimnasta cruza la diagonal haciendo ruedas y finaliza con un mortal hacia adelante
</example>
<example>en la calle cantan las niñas una canción de rueda</example>
<example>
después de la conferencia hubo una rueda de preguntas
</example>
<example>
los niños juegan a la rueda en el centro de la plaza
</example>
<example>sirvieron un plato lleno de ruedas de salchichón</example>
<example>la bicicleta es un vehículo de dos ruedas</example>
<example>prensar las aceitunas con una rueda de molino</example>
<example>estaban todas en rueda, tomando el chocolate</example>
<example>las ruedas de un automóvil</example>
<example>la rueda del pavo es espectacular</example>
<example>ruedas de merluza congelada</example>
<example>cortar las papas en ruedas</example>
<example>la rueda de repuesto</example>
<example>una rueda de carro</example>
<synant>
<synonym>
<syno>rodaja</syno>
<br/>
</synonym>
</synant>
</entry>
<entry id="tienta[2]">
<hw hindex="2">tienta</hw>
<sound>tient02sp.wav</sound>
<fl>feminine noun</fl>
<def>
<svr>
<va>andar a tientas</va>
</svr>
<dt>:to feel one's way, to grope around</dt>
</def>
<synant>
<synonym>
<syno>sonda</syno>
<syno>catéter</syno>
<br/>
</synonym>
</synant>
</entry>
</entry_list>
```

But what this is doing is adding multiple consecutive `<ex_header>` tags (the count being exactly the same as the number of following `<example>` tags within the respective `<entry>` block) before the first `<example>` tag. How can I modify the code to ensure only one tag gets added like this:

```
<entry>
<br>
<abc></abc>
<xyz></xyz>
<ex_header>Example</ex_header>
<example></example>
<example></example>
<example></example>
</entry>
<entry>
<br>
<abc></abc>
<xyz></xyz>
</entry>
<entry>
<br>
<abc></abc>
<xyz></xyz>
<ex_header>Example</ex_header>
<example></example>
<example></example>
</entry>
```

There's got to be some ridiculously simple jquery function that I am missing out on to get the job done.

Comment: can you add code in jsfiddle?

Comment: `$("example:eq(0)").before("<ex_header>");` ?

Comment: Why not: `$("<ex_header>").insertAfter('xyz');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to relate the selector to the current element, otherwise you are matching on all elements in the document. This can be done via `$(this).find()`:

```
$("entry").each(function() { 
    $("<ex_header>").insertBefore($(this).find('example').first()); 
});
```

`$(this)` will be the current element of the outer `.each()` call.

However, you don't need the each loop at all. Just do

```
$("<ex_header>").insertBefore('entry example:first-of-type');
```

Comment: I guess you mean instead: `'entry example:first-of-type'` because using `'entry example:first'` wouldn't work to insert multiple times `<ex_header>`, `:first` works on all document context, unlike `:first-child` or `:first-of-type` which are parent relative selectors

Comment: Thanks a lot! I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `this` context in the iteration to find the `:first` element in current element context

```
$("<ex_header>").insertBefore($(this).find('example:first'));
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>If you want to insert header mutiple times, you can use:</strike>

```
$("<ex_header>").insertAfter('xyz');
```

Following your edit, first one wouldn't work if you don't want to insert if no `example` element follow `xyz`. So you could just use:

<strike>Or:</strike>

```
$("<ex_header>").insertBefore('example:not(example + example)');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try these :-

```
$("entry").each(function() { 
    if ($(this).find("example").length > 0)
    {
        $("<ex_header>").insertBefore('example:first'); 
    }
});
```

It may help you.

Comment: `:first` works matching only first element in the whole DOM, it won't work as expected here